# Parent Child Reference SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I have Parent + Reference tables  where
Reference table is as follows

```
Ref_ID    PARENT_ID    
-------------------
1           1            
2           1            
1           2       
3           2       
1           3       
3           3       
4           3       
2           4       
3           4
```

Trying to return all distinct parent rows WHERE ref_id in ( 2, 3 ) 
using a join instead of using a subquery 
but duplicates are being returned for parent via join query

Any help is appreciated

FYI - there are 4-7 tables in the query ( depending on user selections )so performance is a huge factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

First the code

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(
Ref_ID int,
ParentID int
)

INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1 , 1)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2 , 1)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1 , 2)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3 , 2)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (1 , 3)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3 , 3)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (4 ,3)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (2 , 4)
INSERT INTO @Temp VALUES (3 , 4)

--First Example witout Ref_ID
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ParentID
FROM @Temp
WHERE Ref_ID IN (2,3)

--SECOND Example With Ref_ID
SELECT 
   DISTINCT ParentID,
   Ref_ID
FROM @Temp
WHERE Ref_ID IN (2,3)
```

The first query returns a distinct record of ParentID's. It works fine because i haven't requested for Ref_Id as well.

Just to explain you when you requesting for Ref_ID as well, the query tries to return a distinct ParentID's. But look at your records you have two ParentID's which equals to 4
But with **Different Ref_ID** so he returns them both. both of them matching the query rules
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the insight, guess i was hoping there may be a "magical clause" to void distinct or subquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct parent_field1,parent_field2 
from parent left outer reference
on parent.parent_id=reference.parent_id
where reference.ref_id(2,3)
```